# DalekJS and Mithril: Test are too fast

Tags: google-chrome, dalekjs, mithril.js

I use **Dalek** to test my sample to-do application written with help of **Mithril** framework.

Everything goes fine until `.type()` comes in.

If I `.type()` something in `input` that have bi-directional binding `m.prop` with `m.withAttr` and then `assert` values of that field i get strage behaviour. Instead `"test title"` I get `"tsttle"`. It seems that test are running too quickly for Mithril to capture changes and render them back to DOM.

If assertions for input equality is removed — all works just fine.

Is there any workaround, can I slow down type process?

*P.S. I use **Chrome** browser as test runner.*

Comment: I'm not familiar with Dalek, but am familiar with Mithril. Mithril may be redrawing on every keystroke from your description. Are you using `onchange` with `m.withAttr`?

Comment: No, i use `onkeyup` event. Unfortunatly this is required behavior. I have not tested yet, but I'm pretty shure it will pass tests with `onchange` event for bi-directional check and will have time to render properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That definitely is an interesting issue, the problem is though, that Dalek can't control the speed of the letters typed. This is due to the fact that the JSON-Wire Protocol does not give us a way to handle that, see [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#/session/:sessionId/keys)

One thing you could do, even if it seems like overkill, is to add a long function chain with explicit waits, like this:

```
.type('#selector', 'H')
.wait(500)
.type('#selector', 'e')
.wait(500)
.type('#selector', 'l')
.wait(500)
.type('#selector', 'l')
.wait(500)
.type('#selector', 'o')
```

You also could go ahead & write a utility function that handles that for you

```
function myType (selector, keys, test, wait) {
  var keysArr = keys.split('');
  keysArr.forEach(function (key) {
    test.type(selector, key).wait(wait);
  });

  return test;
}
```

And then use it in your test like this:

```
module.exports = {
  'my test': function (test) {
    test.open('http://foobar.com');
    myType('#selector', 'Hello', test, 500);
    test.done();
  }
};
```

Comment: Since Dalek is in active development and not all features implemented yet (and for current generation of JS frameworks it's "must have feature") - that is a best solution for now. Thanks for Dalek and answer!

Answer (score 1):

Mithril, as of when I'm writing this, does a re-render on onkey* events. An option to avoid this is coming.

You could use attr::config at present to handle the onkey* events as this will not cause a rerender. For example:

```
m('input', {config: addHandler});

function addHandler (el, isInitialized, context) {
  if (!isinitialized) {
    el.addEventListener('onkeyup', keyHandler, false);
  }
}
function keyHandler (event) { /* do something with key press */ }
```

Its possible {config: addHandler, onchange: m.withAttr('value', mpropData)} will do what you want, but I don't know Dalek. If its doesn't, then you can consider updating mpropData inside keyHandler.

Answer (score 0):

Mithril renders asynchronously in response to event handlers (basically so that related groups of events like keypress/input all get a chance to run before redrawing)

You could try a few things:

- if you have access to your data model from your test, you could run your assertion against that model value (which is updated synchronously), as opposed to using the DOM value which only gets updated on the next animation frame
- otherwise, you could force a synchronous redraw by explicitly calling `m.render` (yes, render, not redraw) before running the assertion, to ensure the view is actually in sync w/ the data model
- alternatively, you could try waiting for one animation frame (or two) before running the assertion

Comment: Problem seem to be in Dalek itself as explained by Sebastian Golasch and workaround must be implemented in tests cases.

P.S. Thanks for the great job with Mithril!